# Why a segmentation fault occurs calling a function inside setjmp()?

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, fiber, setjmp

I do not understand why in the function `middleFunc()`, a segmentation fault is raisen when `entry_point(arg)` is invoked inside the `if ( setjmp(middle) )` statement.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <setjmp.h>


    jmp_buf start,middle,end;


    void finalFunc(void *v)
    {
      printf("hello\n");
      return ;
    }


    void middleFunc(void (*entry_point)(void *), void *arg)
    {
     //just debug : this does not cause segmentation fault
     entry_point(arg);

     if ( setjmp(middle) ){
        //this casues the segmentation fault
        entry_point(arg);
        //once the entry point (finalFunc) is executed go to  jmp_buffer end
        longjmp(end,1);
     }
     else {
        longjmp(start,1);
     }
   }

  int main(){

    if (setjmp(end)){
        //exit since finalFunc has been executed
        return 0;
    }

    if (setjmp(start)){
        //the middleFunc has previously set the jmp_buffer middle
        longjmp(middle,1);
    }

    else{
        int  x = 1;
        middleFunc(finalFunc,(void*)&x);
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code the behavior is undefined. You are not allowed to long-jump to `middle` after `middleFunc` finished execution (either by normal completion or by another `longjmp`).

> **7.13.2.1 The longjmp function**
>
> **2** The `longjmp` function restores the environment saved by the most recent invocation of the `setjmp` macro in the same invocation of the program with the corresponding `jmp_buf` argument. If there has been no such invocation, [...] or if the function containing the invocation of the `setjmp` macro has terminated execution<sup>248)</sup> in the interim [...] the behavior is undefined.
>
> 248) For example, by executing a `return` statement or because another `longjmp` call has caused a transfer to a `setjmp` invocation in a function earlier in the set of nested calls.

In your code `middleFunc` sets up `middle` and after that immediately exits to `main` by doing `longjmp(start,1)`. After that jump `middle` is no longer valid. You are no longer allowed to jump to `middle` from anywhere. `setjmp/longjmp` mechanism only supports jumps up the call stack. You cannot do side-jumps or down-jumps. Only up-jumps are supported.

From the practical point of view, you are attempting to jump into a "dead" function invocation and somehow expecting that function parameter values are still valid (like, preserved from the previous invocation or something). But they are not. `setjmp/longjmp` do not preserve/restore parameter values. Value of `entry_point` in that "dead" invocation is probably [some garbage](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f85f6f1aa4620f9f). When you attempt to make a call through `entry_point`, the code coredumps.

P.S. It is true that side-jumping with `setjmp/longjmp` is sometimes used to implement co-routines. However, such usage falls outside the boundaries of standard library specification. And in any case such usage will never expect preservation of parameter values.

Comment: thank you, is this the reason for which co-rotuine are implemented with a new allocated stack ?

Comment: @Neo: At some level, yes, but C simply does not admit coroutines. Any attempt to implement them on top of `setjmp`, rather than via some construct outside the language like assembly or the former-POSIX `ucontext.h` interfaces, is dangerously undefined, and relies on particular implementation details of the C implementation.