# Why does the implementation of user level thread (fiber) require a new allocated stack per fiber?

Tags: c, multithreading, stack, fiber

In C fibers can be coded using `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` to implement context switches at user level.
As described in
[evanjones.ca](http://www.evanjones.ca/software/threading.html) and [Portable Multithreading(pdf)](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/usenix2000/general/full_papers/engelschall/engelschall_html/index.html) it is also required that each fiber has a newly allocated stack.
Since a fiber lives in a thread context, when it is invoked will have  automatically a stack frame associated to it, so why is it required this new allocated stack? : when a fiber wants to switch to another one, the following approach could be used :

```
 cpu_context[N] :global array where the i-th entry is the cpu context(jmp_buffer) of the i-th fiber 

fiber_ith :
   [...]
   if ( setjmp(cpu_context[i]) == 0 ){
        longjmp(cpu_context[j])
   }
   [...]
```

The necessity of a new stack is due to the fact that as written  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51545566/why-a-segmentation-fault-occurs-calling-a-function-inside-setjmp), it is not possible to use  `longjmp()`to go back to a fiber execution whose stack frame is not anymore valid from the instant that fiber calls `longjmp()` ?

EDIT : these fibers must be non preemtive and can voluntary switch from one fiber to another one

Comment: The question is based on false premises. longjmp cannot be used like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose a fiber has a function that calls another function that calls another function that then causes that fiber to be switched for another fiber. When we resume this fiber, we need to ensure that all local variables are back the way they were when the fiber switched and we need to ensure that returning from this function goes back to the calling function.
Thus the following rules emerge:

1. While a fiber is running, it can change its stack.
2. When a fiber is resumed, the stack must be back where it was when the fiber was switched.

It immediately follows from these two rules that every fiber must have its own stack.

Comment: `getcontext` saves the current context, so you use that to save the context of the current fiber when you want to switch to another fiber. Then you find the saved context of the fiber you want to switch to, and switch to it with calling `setcontext`. When you create a new fiber, you also allocate a new stack and initialize the context of the new fiber with that stack. That way each fiber has their own stack, so one fiber does not destroy stuff on the stack of another fiber, and so all the stuff on the stack of a fiber is kept intact and are ready to use again when you switch back to it.

Comment: @nos, perfect the newly allocated stack can ne correctly used with setjmp and getjmp becuase it is noto automatically destroyed as it is the case of simple stack frame

Comment: @Neo if you are using getcontext/setcontext, you have no use for setjmp (note there is no getjmp function).

Comment: @nos, i m sorry, i have made a mistake I wanted to say at the beginning setjmp() and longjmp()

Comment: Sure, but you would have no use for any of those.

Answer (score 1):

First, threads are not intended to manually control their own dispatching. That is, it is not intended that a thread will decide to end or suspend its execution and start another thread. Rather, threads are available to run simultaneously, and the system may run several threads on different physical or virtual processors simultaneously or may start and stop threads so they share available time on a processor.

Because threads may run simultaneously, they must have separate stacks. Each thread will be altering and using its own stack possibly at the same time as other threads are altering and using theirs. These stacks must be separate to avoid conflicts.

Second, `setjmp` and `longjmp` are not intended for jumping to arbitrary points in thread state. A program may use `longjmp` only to return to a previous `setjmp` in its current call stack, in the same thread. You could not, for example, do some work, remember state `A` with `setjmp`, do some more work, remember state `B` with `setjmp`, then `longjmp` to state `A`, and later `longjmp` to state `B`. After the `longjmp` to `A`, `B` is no longer available—whatever was saved for it by `setjmp` is no longer valid.

Comment: Thank you,  with a new stack , setjmp() and longjmp() must be used anyway to implement context switch, right?but the advantage with the stack frame is that it is not automatically deleted after a longjmp()?

Comment: I forgot to say the fibers must be nonpreemtive but can voluntary switch from one fiber to another

Comment: @Neo: `setjmp` and `longjmp` are not for context switching. `longjmp` is just a “long return”—it returns to a previous point in the **current** call stack. It has nothing to do with threads. It is like returning from two or 13 or 50 function calls instead of just one.